# How are the 2 Open IDs linked on StackExchange?

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, authentication

All these days I have been logging into SO with my Gmail Id. Contrarily, yesterday I logged in with my Facebook Id, and I was linked to the same SO account automatically. That was a very handy thing for me, but I am confused as to how this auto linkage happened.
The handle I use for both Gmail & Facebook are same. Is that how this linking happened?
Also, I would like to know what the highlighted statement from **MyLogins** popup means. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That statement means exactly what you've just observed: if you log in with a provider that gives us an email address (and that Stack Exchange trusts enough to *believe* the email that's provided is yours), you can log in with *any other trusted authentication provider* that provides us with the same email.

The key there is that **SE has to trust your provider to not lie about the email you own**. The providers that are "trusted" are Google, Facebook, Yahoo, and [Stack Exchange's own OpenID provider](http://openid.stackexchange.com).

So it's safe because, if you were to log in with Joe's House of OpenIDs and it told us your email was "skonjeet@juno.com", that would be silently ignored.